# Post Request from Angular (TP) to Flask not displaying in Console

Tags: angular, flask

**Hello everybody**

I'm currently trying to make a post request via Angular to Flask in order for me to gather a simple value of a HTML form (Radio Buttons).
I've looked at many others posts on this website and none of them were useful for my situation.

To give a bit of context, my Angular App displays a nested JSON document and I'm trying to gather the result of a radio button form from my  Angular to my Flask backend.
This is my html file (appcomponent.html)

```
 <form class='form' action='http://127.0.0.1:5100/ReceiveImage' method='post'>
<mat-radio-group class="radio" [(ngModel)]='selectedOption3' name='test'>
  <mat-radio-button class="button" *ngFor="let data3 of getThirdkeys(Data[selectedOption][selectedOption2])"
    [value]='data3' name='test'>
    <div class="data3">{{data3}} </div>
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

**In my dataservice.ts I have :**

```
    private Appcomponent : AppComponent

      private Images_DRC = 'http://127.0.0.1:5100/ReceiveImage';

      constructor(private http : HttpClient) {}

      public PostImages() : Observable<any>{
        return this.http.post<any>(this.Images_DRC, {image :this.Appcomponent.selectedOption3});
}
```

**And in my appcomponent.ts I have this :**

```
constructor(private dataService : DataService) {}


ngOnInit () {

  this.dataService.PostImages().subscribe(
    res => {
      console.log(res);
});
```

I've already implemented a GET method to gather the json from Flask and it works perfectly, problem is the POST method doesnt work here.
In the network monitor of Firefox I Clearly see that there are no POST method sent on the specified adress.

**Lastly, here is my Flask code:**

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory, request, send_file
from flask_cors import CORS
import os

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='/GuideDRC/src')
CORS(app)


@app.route("/ReceiveImage", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Get_Image_DRC():
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        projectpath = request.form.get('image')
        return '{}'.format(projectpath)


app.run(debug=True, port=5100)
```

Comment: Why is there a URL in the forms action and why do you make a post in the AppComponent OnInit?

Comment: From what I have read, in the form action you're supposed to specify the url where the result is gonna be sent. In the AppComponent this is where is subscribe to my post method, i've done that for the Get method and wanted to subscribe to both methods in the same "place"